# How to display sprites randomly on left and right side on iphone(portrait mode) using cocos2d?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I'm new to this cocos2d.I'm developing one game in iPhone using cocos2d in that i've to display sprites on left and right side on iPhone (portrait mode). I tried like this.
array_obstacle is a ccarray containing obstacles.
in first part I used array_obstacles  as it is.In second part i scaled that sprite using same obstacles.
Here I used two sprites for displaying sprites on left and right side on iphone(portrait mode).
Now,I want to use only one sprite to display sprites on left and right side on iphone(portrait mode).
can any one suggest me regarding this?

```
int ran = arc4random() % [array_obstacles  count];

randomSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:[array_obstacles  objectAtIndex:ran]];
int minX = 250;//(winSize.width/2)-120;
int maxX =300; //(winSize.width/2)+120;
int rangeX = maxX - minX;
int actualX = (arc4random() % rangeX) + minX;

randomSprite.position = ccp( actualX,winSize.height+randomSprite.contentSize.width);


[spriteSheetBatch addChild:randomSprite];

id actionMove2 = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:1.5 position:ccp(actualX,-randomSprite.contentSize.width)];

[randomSprite runAction:actionMove2];



     int r = arc4random() % [array_obstacles   count];
myRandomSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:[array_obstacles   objectAtIndex:r]];int min_X = -50;//(winSize.width/2)-120;
int max_X =160; //(winSize.width/2)+120;
int range_X = max_X +min_X;
int actual_X = (arc4random() % range_X) + min_X;
myRandomSprite.position = ccp( actual_X,winSize.height+myRandomSprite.contentSize.width);
 id actionMove1 = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:1.5 position:ccp(actual_X,-myRandomSprite.contentSize.width)];                                                         
myRandomSprite.scaleX = -1.0f;
 [myRandomSprite runAction:actionMove1];
```

Comment: int y = arc4random() % [array_obstacles  count];
     randomSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:[array_obstacles  objectAtIndex:y]];
    int actualX;I used this it's working fine.
   
   
 if (y==0||y==1||y==2)
 {
        randomSprite.scaleX=-2.3;
  actualX=(arc4random()%25);
 }
 else {
  
        actualX=(arc4random()%20+220);
 }
 
 randomSprite.position=ccp(actualX,480);
 [spriteSheetBatch addChild:randomSprite];
 
 
 id move2=[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:2.0 position:ccp(actualX,-200)];
 id movefinish=[CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(movefinished:)];